# Independence of real and imaginary parts of the scalar product of multivariate complex normal vectors

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, covariance, independence, complex-numbers

Reading the paper *"Distribution of Inner Product of Two Complex Gaussian Vectors and its Application to MPSK Performance" by Mallik R.K.* I can not get one of the steps.

The author assumes two complex Gaussian vectors
$$\vec{X}\sim\mathcal{CN}(\vec{\mu_X},\mathrm{I}), \\ \vec{Y}\sim\mathcal{CN}(\vec{\mu_Y},\mathrm{I}),\\
\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\Re(x_j)\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(y_i)\Re(y_j)\right]=\delta_{ij},\\
\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\Im(x_j)\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(y_i)\Im(y_j)\right]=\delta_{ij},\\
\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\Re(y_j)\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\Im(y_j)\right]=0.
$$
and is after the joint distribution of real and imaginary parts of their inner product:

$$Z=\vec{Y}^H\!.\vec{X}, \\\ Z_1=\Re(Z),\\ \ Z_2=\Im(Z)$$

It is said in the paper that

> ... it is clear that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ conditioned on $Y$, are independent

But then I went on and found the covariance between  $Z_1, Z_2$ and got a nonzero result, so they can not be independent. Or am I wrong somewhere  in my derivations?

Here they are.

Starting from the definition:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathrm{cov}(z_1,z_2)= \mathrm{cov}\left(\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Re(x_i)+\Im(y_i)\Im(x_i)),\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Im(x_i)-\Im(y_i)\Re(x_i))\right)=\\
&=&\mathrm{E}\left[\left(\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Re(x_i)+\Im(y_i)\Im(x_i))\right)\!\!\left(\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Im(x_i)-\Im(y_i)\Re(x_i))\right)\right]-\\
&-&\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Re(x_i)+\Im(y_i)\Im(x_i))\right]\!\!\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_i(\Re(y_i)\Im(x_i)-\Im(y_i)\Re(x_i))\right]=\\
&=&\mathrm{E}\left[
\sum_i\sum_j\Re(y_i)\Re(y_j)\Re(x_i)\Im(x_j)\right]+\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_i\sum_j\Im(y_i)\Re(y_j)\Im(x_i)\Im(x_j)\right]-\\ 
&-&\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_i\sum_j\Re(y_i)\Im(y_j)\Re(x_i)\Re(x_j)\right]-\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_i\sum_j\Im(y_i)\Im(y_j)\Im(x_i)\Re(x_j)
\right]-\\
&-&\left(\sum_i (\Re(y_i)\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\right]+\Im(y_i)\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\right])\right)\left(\sum_i (\Re(y_i)\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\right]-\Im(y_i)\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\right])\right)=\\
&=&
\sum_i\sum_j\Re(y_i)\Re(y_j)\cancelto{0}{\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\Im(x_j)\right]}+\sum_i\sum_j\Im(y_i)\Re(y_j)\cancelto{\delta_{ij}}{\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\Im(x_j)\right]}-\\ 
&-&\sum_i\sum_j\Re(y_i)\Im(y_j)\cancelto{\delta_{ij}}{\mathrm{E}\left[\Re(x_i)\Re(x_j)\right]}-\sum_i\sum_j\Im(y_i)\Im(y_j)\cancelto{0}{\mathrm{E}\left[\Im(x_i)\Re(x_j)\right]}-\\
&-&\left(\sum_i (\mu_{\Re(x)_i}\Re(y_i)+\Im(y_i)\mu_{\Im(x)_i})\right)\left(\sum_i (\Re(y_i)\mu_{\Im(x)_i}-\Im(y_i)\mu_{\Re(x)_i})\right)=\\
&=&\!\sum_i\!\sum_j\left(\! \Re(y_i)\!\Im(y_j)\!(\mu_{\Re(x)_i}\mu_{\Re(x)_j}\!\!-\!\mu_{\Im(x)_i}\mu_{\Im(x)_j})\!\!+\!\mu_{\Re(x)_i}\mu_{\Im(x)_j}(\Im(y_i)\Im(y_j)\!-\!\Re(y_i)\Re(y_j)\!)\!\!\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
And the last term is clearly not zero (unless the mean is zero).

So where's the mistake?